# How to generate a lost database using hibernated web project

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

I lost a database. But I have the web project hibernated with that database. So could you please help me to generate the entire database with relationships.

Comment: dude database is totally different from hibernate..hibernate just help you out just to save data from model you don't to write any sql query.But you can start from scratch as hibernate will create tables again!!!

Comment: Can you write your hibernate relations

Comment: I can't write relations. It is the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto configuration property to make Hibernate generate the tables according to the Hibernate mappings.

More information can be found [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-optional) in the "Miscellaneous Properties" section.

Comment: Could you please explain me that how to use hbm2ddl